# Show crosshair while holding knife with cl_crosshairstyle 1

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I want to use the special look of the style 1 crosshair, so I do `cl_crosshairstyle 1`.
But from that moment on, the crosshair disappears when I pull my knife out.

Note:
I'm aware that there is  `weapon_reticle_knife_show 1` but that doesn't work on comp servers.

Is there any other way to do it? It must be legal within the ESL rules.

Comment: weapon_reticle_knife_show is a server side command. There is no way to use it in competitive. What you could try is a double bind on the knife to change to the other crosshair while holding it and another bind on the other weapons to change it back.

Comment: Do you got a NVIDIA Graphics Card ? If so, I could explain another way to get a crosshair

Comment: @G.Eiwell yes, I do. That would be nice.

Comment: I used to hear of people using a biro to make a dot or crosshair on their monitor. (Or a tiny piece of masking tape / duct tape). But that sounds rather extreme

Comment: @Smock as you can see under the first answer to this question, we know about that method, but it's against ESL's rules for cs.

Comment: Please update the question to reflect the need to adhere to ESL rules

Comment: @Smock thank you for your input, I did that. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**csgo release notes for 10/7/2019:**

This issue was finally fixed by valve. As you can see in the picture, now, default crosshairs (`cl_crosshairstyle 1`) behave like the others.

[image]

I'm glad this was finally fixed since this has been around since 2014 I think.

Answer (score 5):

One possible way to get a permanent ingame crosshair (only with NVIDIA Geforce Experience):

---

1. **Download** NVIDIA GeForce Experience.
2. **Search for** your "NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\ShaderMod (My path was: "C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Ansel\ShaderMod").
3. **Change** one of the Sticker.png (for example Sticker00.png) with your crosshair png. (For example https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQ0KO.jpg (small Dot-Crosshair)).
4. If not already done, open GeForce Experience again and **activate** the ingame overlay in the "general" settings.
5. **Activate** "Enable experimental features", also in the "general" settings.
6. Then **open up** the ingame overlay with the proper keybind (standart should be ALT+Z).
7. **Click** on "Game Filter" on the left side of the menu -> choose any "style" -> filter by "stickers" -> pick the one you replaced by your crosshair.
8. Now you can **set the the size** of it, while it should always stay on the middle of your screen.
9. After activating your "crosshair sticker" you can **close** the menu with the same keybind.

---

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I know about that solution. There are some gaming monitors that also have a similar feature. But my question was more aiming a specific way of doing that within the game config. Your solution is against the ESL game rules for cs, since you'd have a crosshair on snipers. (and also the crosshair would still be visible during scoping)
Still, thank you for the solution :)